# How to delete contents of user home dir safely via bash

Tags: bash, zip, unzip

I am writing a bash script to do a account restore.  The contents of the home dir is zipped up using this command.

```
sudo sh -c "cd /home/$username; zip -0 -FS -r -b /tmp /home/0-backup/users/$username.zip ."
```

This works as expected.

If the user requests a restore of their data, I am doing the following

```
sudo sh -c "cd /home/$username; rm -rf *"
```

Then

```
sudo -u $username unzip /home/0-backup/users/$username.zip -d /home/$username/
```

This works as expected.

However you can see the flaw in the delete statement, if the username is not set.  We delete all users home dir.  I have if statements that do the checking to make sure the username is there.  I am looking for some advice on a better way to handle resetting the users account data that isn't so dangerous.

One thought I had was to delete the user account and then recreate it. Then do the restore.  I think that this would be less risky. I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: Why wouldn't username be set? That should be part of the argument validation.

Comment: it is set.  I am thinking about what if situations.  I only test if it is set, I have no saine way to test if it is a valid username.  hummm ok that has me thinking

Comment: Safely: I don't know how good `zip` is at detecting changes to the directory it's backing up while it's doing the backup. Perhaps moving the user's directory to `/home/<something_random_and_unique>` first, and _then_ zipping it would be safer. Move it back when done. This can't be done if anything or anyone should be allowed to make changes to the directory at any time though.

Comment: Use `&&` rather then `;` so that you won't execute `rm` if `cd` fails.

Comment: `getent passwd "$username"` has a useful exit status though.

Comment: @Jetchisel Still, the home directory could be gone or have changed after that command has returned that the user exists. Doing this _safely_ is not what I'd call easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the parameters first.

Then use `&&` after `cd` so that it won't execute `rm` if the `cd` fails.

```
if [ -n "$username" ] &&  [ -d "/home/$username" ]
then
    sudo sh -c "cd '/home/$username' && rm -rf * .[^.]*"
fi
```

I added `.[^.]*` in the `rm` command so it will delete dot-files as well. `[^.]` is needed to prevent it from deleting `.` (the user's directory) and `..` (the `/home` directory).

Comment: Thank you all for the input.

Comment: The point about `&&` also applies to the `zip` command, and also if the `zip` command fails you shouldn't proceed to the deletion section. Basically, *every* command needs to have error checking and an appropriate abort path.

Comment: I suck at regex, how can get it also not delete   somefile.zip along with the . and .. ? something like
sudo sh -c "cd '/home/$username' && rm -rf * .[^.]* !($username.zip)"

Comment: `rm -rf` deletes all the directories. You can't delete directories if you want to leave zip files in them.

Comment: FYI, wildcards are not regexp.

Comment: the zip fille is in the root dir

Comment: `rm -rf !($username.zip) .[^.]*`

Comment: $ sudo sh -c "cd /home/demo && rm -rf !(demo.zip) .[^.]*"
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: Did you enable `shopt -s extglob`?